# "No route matches" - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby and Rails. This is my second application where I'm trying to implement login authentication.

#### Getting this error

```
No route matches "/user/process_login"
```

Here is my `routes.rb`

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "user/login"
  get "user/process_login"
end
```

On submit i am getting above error on login page. I think something has gone wrong in `routes.rb` or somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you're trying to post to that route,

try changing your routes file to this:

```
post "user/process_login"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in your `routes.rb`

```
get "user/login" => "users#login"
get "user/process_login" => "users#process_login"
```

on a side note, I highly recommend that you use `post` instead of `get` to process the login.